# Toggle onClick function

Tags: jquery

I want to toggle two boxes color each time on a button. Box1 works but Box2 does not work.

```
$(function () {
    $(':button').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();                    
        let box1 = $('#box1');
        let box2 = $('#box2');
        if ($(box1).hasClass('pink') || $(box2).hasClass('yellow')) {
            $(box1).toggleClass('yellow');
            $(box2).toggleClass('pink');
        } 
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that style for class `yellow` is having higher precedence than style for class `pink` because of which you even if you add `pink` class to `box2`, style does not get updated as `yellow` class overrides its styles whereas style for `box1` gets updated.

Try following

```js
$(function() {

  $(':button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let box1 = $('#box1');
    let box2 = $('#box2');
    $(box1).toggleClass('pink yellow');
    $(box2).toggleClass('yellow pink');
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.pink {
  background-color: pink;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button">Toggle</button>
<div id="box1" class="pink"></div>
<div id="box2" class="yellow"></div>
```

Comment: So it will toggle by order?

Comment: It will toggle the classes. As it will be an atomic operation, hence, order does not matter. toggle simply adds the missing classes and removes the applied classes.

Comment: Glad to help you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Considering by default your `#box1` has class `yellow` and `#box2` has class `pink`. So you can simply right it like below without adding any if conditions.

```
$(function () {
  $(':button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();                    
    $('#box1').toggleClass('yellow pink');
    $('#box2').toggleClass('pink yellow');
    return false;
  });
});
```